# Syntax error: "(" unexpected -- with !(*.sh) in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, for-loop, ffmpeg

I want to run a sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in !(*.sh); do
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf yadif=0:-1 -threads 0 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
        -r 29.97 -b:v 3000k -s 1280x720 -preset:v slow -profile:v Main \
        -level 3.1 -bf 2 -movflags faststart /mnt/media/out-mp4/"${f%.mxf}.mp4"
    rm $f
done
```

However, I get the following error:

```
2: task1.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

If I try directly on the command line it works perfectly.

> the path and permissions are already reviewed

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: The `rm` should use quotes around the file name argument just like the rest of the script. In general, any variable which holds a file name needs to be double-quoted. The problem will not manifest with trivial file names, but production code needs to cope with arbitrary file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a "sh file" -- it's a **bash** script. If you run it with `sh yourscript`, it will not work (as extglobs, the shell feature you're trying to use, aren't supported in POSIX sh); it needs to be run only with `bash yourscript`, or with `./yourscript` when starting with `#!/bin/bash` (as it does). Describing it as a "sh file" is thus misleading. Moreover, even with bash, the extended globbing feature needs to be turned on.

---

Your immediate issue is that `!(*.sh)` is not regular glob syntax; it's [an extglob extension](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language), not available by default. You may have a `.bashrc` or similar configuration file which enables this extension for interactive shells, but that won't apply to scripts. Run:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

...to enable these features.

---

Cleaned up, your script might look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

# putting settings in an array allows unescaped newlines in definition
# also sorted to make it easier to find things.
settings=(
  -b:v 3000k
  -bf 2
  -c:v libx264
  -level 3.1
  -movflags faststart
  -pix_fmt yuv420p
  -preset:v slow
  -profile:v Main
  -r 29.97
  -s 1280x720
  -threads 0
  -vf yadif=0:-1
)

for f in !(*.sh); do
    ffmpeg "${settings[@]}" -i "$f" \
      /mnt/media/out-mp4/"${f%.mxf}.mp4" && rm -- "$f"
done
```

Note the following changes, above and beyond formatting:

- `shopt -s extglob` is on its own line, before the glob is expanded.
- The `rm` is only run if `ffmpeg` succeeds, because the separator between those commands is `&&`, rather than either `;` or a bare newline.
- The `--` argument passed to `rm` tells it to treat all future arguments (in this case, the content of `"$f"`) as a filename, even if it starts with a dash.
- The `"$f"` argument to `rm` is inside double quotes.

Comment: Thank you, works great however in a crontab `(*/2 * * * * cd /mnt/media/in-mp4/ && ./task_mp4.sh >> /tmp/task_mp4.log 2>&1)` fails `./task_mp4.sh: line 23: ffmpeg: command not found`

Comment: @JmvJmv, make sure you set a `PATH` that includes your ffmpeg install location. The default PATH for cron jobs is often very minimal. You can set environment variables at the top of your crontab -- if your ffmpeg is in `/usr/local/bin`, for instance, you could put `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` there.

Comment: @JmvJmv, ...similar applies for any other runtime dependencies -- if your ffmpeg depends on libraries in locations not referenced by `/etc/ld.so.conf{,.d/*}`, then you'll want to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at the top of the crontab. That's just a list of key-value pairs, not a shell script, so no `export` commands or similar.

Comment: @JmvJmv, ...btw, if you're on Linux, you can read the PATH that your cron daemon is using easily. The following is a bit evil (for reasons related to [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)), but: `for cron_pid in $(pgrep cron); do tr '\0' '\n' <"/proc/$cron_pid/environ" | grep -e '^PATH='; done`

Comment: Works, adding `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"` at the top of task_mp4.sh. However when I do a MXF transcode, I need a bmx library in that sense add `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` at the top of task_mxf.sh but doesn't work **bmxtranswrap: command not found** Any idea ?

Comment: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is generally needed at compile time, not runtime. Are you sure what you're missing isn't, say, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Also do make sure `/usr/local/bin` is in your PATH, if that's where `bmxtranswrap` is.

Comment: If the problem looks like a missing dynamic library, `ldd` is your friend for debugging those problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the extended globbing in the script:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Also make sure you're not running the script in a different script, e.g. by calling `sh script.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are running this script `sh code.sh`. This means you are using `sh` to run the script, but the first line (`#!/bin/bash`) implies it's been written for `bash`.

On some systems `sh` and `bash` are the same, but on others they are not; and, when invoked as `sh`, `Bash` turns off some non-POSIX features. So it's important to use the right shell and the right invocation.

Use `bash code.sh` or better still, make the script executable (`chmod a+x code.sh`) and then run it directly (`./code.sh`)